# AWS Lambdas CI with multiple repos

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-integration

I have a microservices web application project where every service has its own GitHub repository.
The project uses Lambda functions for each microservice endpoint (es. get-by-id, get-all, etc..) and every repository has its own template.yml file that describes the service structure with functions, gateway and database tables.

If I deploy every single one of these repositories with CI GitHub actions as result I have multiple lambda applications and multiple API Gateways instead of a single API Gateway with a single base URL connected to all of my Lambda functions to use inside my frontend applications.

What I am trying to figure out is the best/right way to manage the infrastructure because I am not sure or expert enough to find the right solution for this problem.
I tried to search inside the AWS documentation and the forum and even I found a bunch of examples, none of these helped me to fully understand what I have to do to solve this problem in the right way.

In the end, what is the preferred way to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (and often do in similar projects), is that I use Terraform to deploy the infrastructure and have a remote state to be shared across CI pipelines.

Comment: That's sound like a good idea! I am digging into it, thanks for the fast reply!